# llvm callgraphscc pass causes core dump

Tags: llvm

I wrote an `llvm callgraphscc pass`, it's very simple as following:

```
bool MyCallGraphSCCPass::runOnSCC(CallGraphSCC& SCC) {
    for (CallGraphSCC::iterator it = SCC.begin(); it != SCC.end(); it++) {
        CallGraphNode* node = *it;
        Function* func = node->getFunction();
    }
    return false;
}
```

This just works fine. However, if I want to print the name of each function as following:

```
bool MyCallGraphSCCPass::runOnSCC(CallGraphSCC& SCC) {
    for (CallGraphSCC::iterator it = SCC.begin(); it != SCC.end(); it++) {
        CallGraphNode* node = *it;
        Function* func = node->getFunction();
        func->getName();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then it can compile (obviously), but when I use `opt` to run this, there appears an error as following:

```
0  opt                    0x0000000001603412 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(_IO_FILE*) + 34
1  opt                    0x0000000001602cb4
2  libpthread.so.0        0x00007fd3155f8cb0
3  opt                    0x00000000014a86e0 llvm::AttributeSet::getAttributes(unsigned int) const + 0
4  opt                    0x00000000014a8748 llvm::AttributeSet::hasAttribute(unsigned int, llvm::Attribute::AttrKind) const + 8
5  call_graph_scc_pass.so 0x00007fd3146062ad test::MyCallGraphSCCPass::runOnSCC(llvm::CallGraphSCC&) + 61
6  opt                    0x00000000012aa9aa
7  opt                    0x0000000001591188 llvm::legacy::PassManagerImpl::run(llvm::Module&) + 904
8  opt                    0x000000000059387b main + 2811
9  libc.so.6              0x00007fd31482976d __libc_start_main + 237
10 opt                    0x00000000005b700d
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: opt -load call_graph_scc_pass.so -scc 
1.  Running pass 'CallGraph Pass Manager' on module '<stdin>'.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can some one help me with this?

Comment: In addition, I ran another `function pass` doing the same thing (print the name of the `function`), and that just worked fine. The problem occurred when I was running this `callgraphscc pass`.

Comment: Do you have calls to inline ASM in your IR?

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the function in the `CallGraph` is `isDeclaration()` or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `node->getFunction()` may return a null-pointer and you're not checking for this before dereferencing it.

A `CallGraphNode` is added to the call graph for all functions in the module without internal linkage. This is because there is a possibility that it *could* be called from another module. Of course, this is not reachable from the current module, so the caller function is null.

A `CallGraphNode` is also added if a function address is used for something other than a direct call (such as being stored into memory). It may be called later in a way that the caller can't be tracked statically, so the function field is null here too.